# Slope height calculation in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I want to know if there exists some method to calculate the slope height from a DEM 1X1 m?

So I intend to find the rise (vertical), not the run (horizontal). I try to calculate using the slope length and the sin function of the angle, but the results are still with errors in the flat areas.

---

With Slope function I carried put the angle, but not the rise. So, the angle is in degrees, but the rise should be in meters, like a DEM. I didn't find any function to complete this rise calculation. [image]

Comment: Slope is the rise/fall over a distance (horizontal), in order to know the height you need also the horizontal distance covered. No doubt you have the Slope tool in spatial analyst which will give the results in percent rise or degree; can you draw a picture of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Keep in mind that if your DEM is in degrees your slopes will be nonsensical if you don't make sure unit conversion is present.

Answer (score 1):

if you compute the percentage of slope and multiply it by the size of the cell,you get the change in Y. However, this might be an issue for you along the diagonals, depending how you wih to process this.

Another way to see your problem is that you need the maximum difference between your pixel and its neighbour. You can therefore use the focal statistics tool with a square neighbourhood (3*3) and the maximum value, then you compute the difference between your raster and the max raster, which gives you the rise.